# Terraform foreach list of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, list, foreach, terraform, aws-security-group

I am looking for help to foreach over a list of objects in Terraform.

I have the following:

local.distinct_rule_list =

```
      + {
          + customer_name = "test125231"
          + rightsubnet   = [
              + "10.41.0.0/16",
            ]
        },
      + {
          + customer_name = "test125231"
          + rightsubnet   = [
              + "10.71.0.0/16",
            ]
        },
      + {
          + customer_name = "real-test-4-2323"
          + rightsubnet   = [
              + "10.42.0.0/16",
            ]
        },
    ]
```

I would like to use it in the following:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "dh_ingress_sg_rule" {
  for             = local.distinct_rule_list
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8000
  to_port           = 8080
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = each.value["rightsubnet"]
  description       = each.value["customer_name"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sgtest.id
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on sg.tf line 42, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "dh_ingress_sg_rule":
│   42:   for_each          = local.distinct_rule_list
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.distinct_rule_list is list of object with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
│ must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type
│ list of object.
╵
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
ERRO[0017] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the issue? Any errors? What `local.distinct_rule_list`? Its definition nor values are shown.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the recommendation. I updated with the details requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "dh_ingress_sg_rule" {
  for_each          = {for idx, val in local.distinct_rule_list: idx=>val}
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8000
  to_port           = 8080
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = each.value["rightsubnet"]
  description       = each.value["customer_name"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sgtest.id
}
```